# python script run failed in crontab while meeting local()

Tags: python, cron, local, fabric

I'm trying to run a python script in crontab.

```
5 0 * * *  python /home/hadoop/import_openapp.py >> /home/hadoop/openapp.out 2>&1
```

The python script is something like below:

```
import sys
import datetime
from fabric.api import local

ystd = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
c = ystd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(c)
print('Start to format file ...')
......
print('Start to upload on HDFS ...')
local("/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put " + finalfile + " /user/hadoop/yunying/openapp")
print('Start to upload on MaxCompute ...')
......
```

When the crontab is called, the log file is like:

```
2016-07-01
Start to format file ...
Start to upload on HDFS ...
[localhost] local: /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put /data/uxin/nsq_client_active_collect/hadoop/openappfinal.log /user/hadoop/yunying/openapp
```

And then, the process is over. I cannot find it in `ps -ef|grep python`

Why it comes to an end while meeting `local()`?

Comment: Anything that's run from cron is run with a pretty minimal environment, so if you rely on having a tweaked PYTHONPATH, that's probably why.

Comment: Have you tried to launch the command /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put /data/uxin/nsq_client_active_collect/hadoop/openappfinal.log /user/hadoop/yunying/openapp from shell? Is it cron set to right user's crontab? Any permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the PYTHONPATH it not set up correctly for whatever the user that CRON is using to run the script. Print out the path to a debug file to check:

```
with open('/path/to/debug_file.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(str(sys.path))
```

Try adding the line:

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/fabric.api")
```

before importing local

You can also dynamically get the location of the file that is being run using

```
import os
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

this will allow you to use relative paths if you need them

Comment: I found the problem.Not the `local()`, but JAVA_HOME is not set while running `hadoop fs -put` command.Thanks!